# How to avoid ambiguous name of the base class with the same name of register defination from manufacturer

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, namespaces, ambiguous, atmelstudio

I am deriving a base class named (**Class Adc**). There is also a manufacturer's header file which has a **struct** for ADC registers with name **Adc**.

When I am trying to use ADC struct in my child class, compiler confuses it with the base class. Also, the base class is part of the "symm" namespace, while the struct is part of the global namespace.

Is there any way I can avoid this ambiguity in names without changing both names. The base class is used in many projects. Changing the base class name would create some trouble in other projects. I don't want to touch manufacturer's header too.

This is the Struct from Manfacturer I am talking about:

```
 /** \brief ADC hardware registers */
#if !(defined(__ASSEMBLY__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ASM__))
typedef struct {
  __IO ADC_CTRLA_Type            CTRLA;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x00 (R/W  8) Control A */
  __IO ADC_CTRLB_Type            CTRLB;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x01 (R/W  8) Control B */
  __IO ADC_REFCTRL_Type          REFCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x02 (R/W  8) Reference Control */
  __IO ADC_EVCTRL_Type           EVCTRL;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x03 (R/W  8) Event Control */
  __IO ADC_INTENCLR_Type         INTENCLR;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x04 (R/W  8) Interrupt Enable Clear */
  __IO ADC_INTENSET_Type         INTENSET;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x05 (R/W  8) Interrupt Enable Set */
  __IO ADC_INTFLAG_Type          INTFLAG;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x06 (R/W  8) Interrupt Flag Status and Clear */
  __I  ADC_SEQSTATUS_Type        SEQSTATUS;   /**< \brief Offset: 0x07 (R/   8) Sequence Status */
  __IO ADC_INPUTCTRL_Type        INPUTCTRL;   /**< \brief Offset: 0x08 (R/W 16) Input Control */
  __IO ADC_CTRLC_Type            CTRLC;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x0A (R/W 16) Control C */
  __IO ADC_AVGCTRL_Type          AVGCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x0C (R/W  8) Average Control */
  __IO ADC_SAMPCTRL_Type         SAMPCTRL;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x0D (R/W  8) Sample Time Control */
  __IO ADC_WINLT_Type            WINLT;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x0E (R/W 16) Window Monitor Lower Threshold */
  __IO ADC_WINUT_Type            WINUT;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x10 (R/W 16) Window Monitor Upper Threshold */
  __IO ADC_GAINCORR_Type         GAINCORR;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x12 (R/W 16) Gain Correction */
  __IO ADC_OFFSETCORR_Type       OFFSETCORR;  /**< \brief Offset: 0x14 (R/W 16) Offset Correction */
       RoReg8                    Reserved1[0x2];
  __IO ADC_SWTRIG_Type           SWTRIG;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x18 (R/W  8) Software Trigger */
       RoReg8                    Reserved2[0x3];
  __IO ADC_DBGCTRL_Type          DBGCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x1C (R/W  8) Debug Control */
       RoReg8                    Reserved3[0x3];
  __I  ADC_SYNCBUSY_Type         SYNCBUSY;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x20 (R/  16) Synchronization Busy */
       RoReg8                    Reserved4[0x2];
  __I  ADC_RESULT_Type           RESULT;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x24 (R/  16) Result */
       RoReg8                    Reserved5[0x2];
  __IO ADC_SEQCTRL_Type          SEQCTRL;     /**< \brief Offset: 0x28 (R/W 32) Sequence Control */
  __IO ADC_CALIB_Type            CALIB;       /**< \brief Offset: 0x2C (R/W 16) Calibration */
} Adc;
#endif /* !(defined(__ASSEMBLY__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ASM__)) */
```

This is my child class definition:

```
class ADC_SAML21 : public Adc
    {
        public:

            ADC_SAML21(bool interruptable = false);
}
```

Thank you.

Regards,
Rishit

Answer (score 0):

In the places where the compiler can't figure out which `Adc` you're referring to, you can use the scope operator to specify which one.  Use `symm::Adc` for the base class (or possibly `::symm::Adc`), and `::Adc` for the global struct.